# NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802) in ios 9

Tags: ios, httprequest, nsurlconnection, xcode7.1beta, ios9.1

I got this error when I try to fetch images through server.
Here is my code for fetch image through server:

```
-(void)downloadThumbnailWithHeight:(NSInteger)height width:(NSInteger)width callback:(void (^)(UIImage*))callback {
    NSString* key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ldx%ld", (long)width, (long)height];
    UIImage* __block thumbnail = [_thumbnails objectForKey:key];
    if (thumbnail) { callback(thumbnail); return; }
    HttpRequest* request = [HttpRequest requestWithRelativePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/api/v1/incident/%@/resize?height=%d&width=%d",self.uuid, (int)height, (int)width]];
    [HttpResponse processAsynchronousRequest:request onCompletion:^(HttpResponse* response) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithData:response.responseData];
            if (!thumbnail) thumbnail = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gray_thumbnail_background.png"];
            [_thumbnails setObject:thumbnail forKey:key];
            callback(thumbnail);
        });
    }];
}
```

Before I ask this question in stackoverflow I already try to add this in my info.plist. Here is my plsit:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>To Find out your location</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>To Find out your location</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.abc.def</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>BNDL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

But it still not working.
IT give me following error when I launch the app:

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource
>   load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via
>   your app's Info.plist file.

Please help me because I already take two much of time to solve this issue.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: after adding NSAllowsArbitraryLoads in plist you should try deleting app and delete derived data folder of Xcode and clean and run project....! it work for me..!

Answer (score 2):

If you are for some reasons prefer to use `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` key to ignore security restrictions you must place it inside `NSAppTransportSecurity` dictionary, for that just put your dict under `NSAppTransportSecurity` key.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
<dict>  
     <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
</dict>
```

However it's not recommended and may cause to a rejection of your app by Apple.
Apple is very clear in that they intend to reject apps who use this flag without a specific reason.

The better solution could be to add an exception to a specific domain.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/index.html

Your `NSAppTransportSecurity` section then may look like:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
     <key>yourdomain.com</key>
     <dict>
       <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
       <true/>
       <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
       <true/>
       <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
       <string>TLSv1.2</string>
     </dict>
   </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: I already try this but still not working any other suggestion?

Comment: Please check my updated question. Is there any issue in my plist?

Comment: Its not "You should", its "you can temporarily as a workaround". But defiantly not "should". The word should implies this is a recommended practice people must be doing.

Comment: @MartinH fully agree with you, I will edit my post. It's definitely not a good practice at all.